# How to get the most popular page under a section using Site Catalyst (Omniture)?

Tags: api, analytics, adobe-analytics

I want to use the site catalyst api to get the most popular page (page that has maximum pageviews) under a given site-section? Let me explain better with an example.

My website has multiple channels (News/Journals/Books/Events etc). Each of the channel has many pages under it. I want a api call that will get the most popular news page or Journals page or Books page etc.

I am passing data to sitecatalyst like this..

```
s.pageName = o_title;
s.channel = o_structure
s.prop1 = o_iden
```

where o_title has the page title of a newspage or a journalpage etc..
o_structure refers to either "News" or "Journals" or "Books" etc.

Currently I am able to only get the most popular page on the entire site. I would appreciate  if someone can help me find the most popular page per section.

Thanks,
Rag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already know the basics of using the Omniture API, how to queue up a report and look for status and get it etc... here is a basic REST data string to get site sections (s.channel) broken down by page names (s.pageName) with page views as metric. You will use the `Report.QueueRanked` API method, and you need to specify the rsid(s) to get the data from and the date ranges.

```
{
  "reportDescription": {
    "reportSuiteID":"RSID",
    "dateFrom":"YYYY-MM-DD",
    "dateTo":"YYYY-MM-DD",
    "metrics":[   
      {
        "id":"pageViews"
      }
    ],
    "sortBy":"pageViews",
    "elements":[
      {
        "id":"siteSection"
      },
      {
        "id":"page"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Crayon, Thanks for the reply. But I am not able to get this to work. I use Java to hit the webservice and I can get the List of site sections and its page views and visits. But if I have to get a list of site section pages ordered by pageview I am not able to. So like you said I added another element scElement2.setId("page") but it now gives me a report status "failed".

Comment: well...I did a test query on one of my own report suites and it worked okay for me...but I did it with php using REST.  I don't really know java, and if you're using SOAP, i don't really know SOAP either. I do know from reading in adobe's docs that a lot of the report requests will not work with the SOAP method so if you're using SOAP I would first suggest you try using REST instead.

Comment: Ok. I think what is happening is, its not accepting two elements. I can have just "pages" and get all the pages and its pageviews and like wise "siteSection" and get the pageView count. But if I have to include both "page" and "siteSection" it does not like it and it returns with reportStatus "failed".

Comment: so..are you using REST or SOAP?  If REST.. dumb question: are using a comma to separate the two?

Comment: I am using Wsdl2java to create the wsdl client. I think this will call the api using SOAP. I dont separate the two by comma. I create an array with two elements and populate each. Like :    ReportDefinitionElement [] elements = new ReportDefinitionElement[2]; 
   ReportDefinitionElement element = new ReportDefinitionElement(); 
   element.setId( "page" ); 
   elements[0] = element; 
   element = new ReportDefinitionElement(); 
   element.setId( "pageSection" ); 
   elements[1] = element; 
   scReport.setElements(elements);

Comment: are you able to post the actual SOAP request being made?

Comment: Also just a fyi - I tried this on asp.net (c#) as well and I got the same error. Interestingly the error code on both the tries is 6001. I dont know what is happening. In the backend i have created a taffic data correlation between channel and pageName and I can see the report breakdown by siteSection. I am not able to get this using api. Pls let me know if this info gives you any clue on what is happening.

Comment: I really don't know what the problem could be without better insight into what you are actually doing.  You are using the `Report.QueueRanked` method, yes?  I know that you cannot use multiple elements if you use for instance `Report.QueueOvertime`.  Are you able to post the actual SOAP request being made?  Also I was looking around on the developer forums and it looks like you might be getting that error if the amount of data you are requesting is too large.  What date range are you trying to use? Can you try doing it with a smaller date range like just 1 day as a test?

Comment: Yes, I am using ReportQueueRanked. I am using sitecatalyst 1.5v. I am pointing to the "dev" environment. I just have very less data ~ 50. I dont know how I can get the soap request as of now. I will get that soon and will update you. In the meanwhile I will also try using php and rest to see if that gets the result I am looking for. Do you have any step by step tutorial on how to use php to access reporting api? Thanks Crayon Violent for answering all my questions so far. I really appreciate it.

Comment: https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/how-to-start-with-the-omniture-rest-api-in-php is a good article for using php and REST,  It's the one I used. Be sure to download the PhpRestClient script from the github link at the beginning of the article.

Comment: Thanks Crayon Violent. I managed to get this work in Java itself by using REST Service. I think REST is the way to go. And just for the record, I used this link to get going... https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/calling-rest-api-in-java

Comment: Sweet...yeah like I said..I have seen in the documents that some of the stuff doesn't work with SOAP. I'm not going to pretend to know why but since I have seen that, I just learned the REST method from the getgo and haven't had issues with it. Glad you got it sorted!